# Regular Expression to Match and Highlight With a Lot of Variance

Tags: jquery, regex, filter

I've taken a few swings at this, but I'll post my issue and my most recent successful code.

If you're familiar with Sublime Text, this will make sense much more quickly. If not, I'll do my best to explain, but I definitely recommend the program as a side note.

The goal is to match titles given a search string and highlight the match. The catch is that the match can be in any order, and doesn't have to signify the beginning of the string, and that strings are separated by spaces in the original input

Example:

```
String to Match: "Hello World"

Does it match? 
"hello" -> Yes!
"h w" -> Yes!
"el orl" -> Yes!
"World Hello" -> Yes!
"Hello Foo" -> No!
```

So the input is very forgiving. I have it to the point where I can match the text and determine whether or not to show the result. I'm just stuck at getting highlighting to work. I may be taking the wrong approach, but here is what I have:

```
$('#sdfilter').live('keyup change', function() {
    var inText = $(this).val().trim(); //remove trailing whitespace
    var blocks = $('.listing'); //blocks to loop through

    $.each(blocks, function() {
        var title = $(this).children('.title').text(); //the title in the block
        if (matchAll(title, inText)) {
            $(this).show();
        } else {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    })

})

matchAll = function(string, args) { //string= string to match, args= search input
    var die = 0; //return switch
    var checks = args.split(' '); //break input into array
    $.each(checks, function() {
        var myReg = new RegExp(this, 'i'); //search term to regex
        if (!string.match(myReg)) { //if it doesn't match, kill the function
            die = 1;
        } 
    })

    if (die == 1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I've tried doing a replace withing the `$.each(checks, function() {...})` loop to add `<span>` tags, but then the input string matches the span tags themselves as it loops around.

I've found solutions that are very close, but not quite as dynamic as I'm hoping for. So my official question is: Am I moving in the right direction? And if so, what am I missing here?

**EDIT**

Sorry, I guess I wasn't clear enough. I need to know how to move forward such that what is matched will be highlighted. Using above example and '[ ]' to signify highlighting

```
String to Match: "Hello World"

Does it match? 
"hello" -> Yes! -> "[Hello] World"
"h w" -> Yes! -> "[H]ello [W]orld"
"el orl" -> Yes! -> "H[el]lo W[orl]d"
"World Hello" -> Yes! -> "[Hello] [World]"
"Hello Foo" -> No! -> **hidden
```

The highlighting is done by wrapping the matches in `span` tags

**EDIT 2**

When trying something like `string = string.replace(myReg, '<span>' + this + '</span>')` (as an else statement to `if (!string.match(myReg))` )I end up getting the `<span>` elements themselves matched. I suppose this can be expected, as the same input is looped over repeatedly. Is there a way to exclude them from the myReg?  Small code block for reference:

```
...
$.each(checks, function() {
        var myReg = new RegExp(this, 'i'); //search term to regex
        if (!string.match(myReg)) { //if it doesn't match, kill the function
            die = 1;
        } else {
            string = string.replace(myReg, '<span>' + this + '</span>');
        }
    })
...
```

Comment: Looks ok to me. Is there anything not working as expected?

Comment: Your `matchAll` method doesn't seem to be working the way you want it to. Shouldn't this return true if it accomplished your goal? `matchAll("h w","Hello World")` The first argument is the string you are testing, and the second argument is the string you are matching against. Right? Can you be a little more specific in what can match and what wont? From what you've posted, it looks like you just want to match atleast 1 letter from each word.

Comment: Does swapping the arguments make it any better? currently it looks like it would only match `hello world`, swapping would make it match a lot more. `matchAll(inText, title)`

Comment: @KevinB Yeah, the string argument is the string to match. Args is the search string to translate to regex. That's the way I pass it in now. Sorry, I'll edit to make the variables more clear

Comment: In the last case, do you want to match the "Hello" but not the "Foo" part?

Comment: No. to be more real worldish, you would want to match 'Toy Cam' to Toyota Camri, but not 'Toy Prius'. It's misleading in the sense that if it matched that record, the user would be led to believe that their search term 'prius' matched, even though that entry does not exist in the database

Comment: edited with highlighting code included

Comment: @KyleMacey I have updated my fiddle below. Everything seems to be working now.

Comment: @sgarrett it's still a bit buggy. typing stuff like "green hello" and a few other terms rearrange the original data. I haven't had a lot of extra time to dig into this one, but I think I have a different concept I'm going to give a shot soon. Accepted answer for your diligence, and if I figure out, I'll hit you up on your blog. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding with this is that OP is saying if the values inputted are all in the "string to match" then it is considered a match.

I've made a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JYsJU/20/). The main fix is to use `.text()`. I've commented the code to help you see what's going on.

Comment: Amazing. I was starting to lose hope. Had to modify slightly to match the ".title" class, as a block has other text I don't want matched. Other than that, it worked beautifully!

Comment: Oh no wait! Found a bug in it! Tentatively removing accepted answer, sorry... http://jsfiddle.net/kmacey1249/JYsJU/7/ Use search term "He green".

Comment: @KyleMacey I have updated the fiddle. I'm not seeing issues now.

Comment: issue persists with "He span" or "He class"

Comment: @KyleMacey Try to break it now. :P

Comment: You're going to hate me... Most things work, but some inputs overload and crash the browser without explanation. It seems like any term that BEGINS with 'o' or 'e' will crash it. I can't figure out why. however, beginning with 'h' is okay, and typing 'hello' is fine, which has both e and o in it.

Comment: I feel like such an ass, but at least you'll work for the accepted answer ;)

Comment: @KyleMacey Updated. Yeah this is my last effort. Take it from here. :P